# What is meant by "resurrecting a player"?

Tags: civilization-5

Civilization V's [Fall 2012 balance patch](http://store.steampowered.com/news/9258/) mentions resurrecting a player:

> - Resurrecting a player will have both sides forget any denouncing that happened before resurrected.

What is Firaxis referring to by the term "resurrecting a player"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resurrecting a player occurs when that player has been eliminated from the game due to losing all their cities, and then you capture one of their (former) cities and choose to return it to them, thus bringing them back into the game.